# Abgrenzung Tag (24h) und Tag/Nacht

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, technical-terminology

Im beruflichen Alltag fällt mir immer wieder die nicht schlüssige Begriffsabgrenzung zwischen dem Tag als Zeiteinheit (24h) und dem Tag als Gegensatz zur Nacht auf.
Hierbei handelt es sich in diesem Sinne ja quasi um einen Tag im Tag. Dies führt zu Fehlinterpretationen, etwa von Kennwerten die sich nur auf den Tageszeitraum 06:00-22:00 Uhr beziehen.

Konkreter: Ich befinde mich im Bereich der Verkehrstechnik und rede oft von täglichen Verkehren oder Kfz/Tag (=Kfz/24h). Für mich ist immer nur der ganze Tag relevant. Gebe ich meine Berechnungen an einen Lärmtechniker weiter, spricht dieser von Tages- und Nachtverkehren und meint damit ganz spezifische Zeiträume. Es geht also nicht um flexible Zeiträume ("heller Tag") o. ä. sondern um per Regelwerk gesetzte Zeiträume (die in anderen Regelwerken, Definitionen, o. Ä. durchaus anders sein können). Dies führt in unserer Kommunikation, schriftlich wie mündlich immer wieder zu Irritation auf einer Seite oder falschen Annahmen.

Gibt es für eine der beiden Bezeichnungen eine sinnvolle Alternativbezeichnung?

Nachtrag: Ich suche nicht nach Umschreibungen, Typisierungen oder anderen Arten, wie Tag definiert werden kann, sondern nach einer sprachlichen Lösung meines Problems, dass mit Tag manchmal 24h, manchmal der Gegensatz zur Nacht gemeint ist. Wie genau sich die Zeiträume definitorisch ausgestalten (Uhrzeiten, hell/dunkel, Arbeit/Freizeit, o. ä.) sollte dabei vollkommen irrelevant sein.

Comment: Als Muttersprachler ist mir ein Problem bei der Mehrbedeutung noch nie bewusst untergekommen: Üblicherweise ergibt sich die echte Bedeutung sehr einfach aus dem Kontext. Hast Du vielleicht ein konkretes Beispiel? "Tagsüber" wird gerne verwendet, wenn der Tag als Gegensatz zur Nacht gemeint ist, aber so wie sie gestellt ist, ist die Frage -imho- zu allgemein

Comment: Da fällt mir so ein Spruch ein: *Der Tag hat 24 Stunden, und wenn das nicht reicht, nehmen wir noch die Nacht dazu.* Ich denke, die Alternativbezeichnungen hängen stark vom Kontext ab. Vielleicht solltest Du die Frage etwas konkretisieren.

Answer (score 2):

Es kommt auf den Kontext an:

Ein astronomischer Tag im Sinne von Sonnenauf- bis -untergang ändert sich in seiner Länge täglich. Insofern ist Tag relativ eindeutig, gerade wenn es um irgendwelche täglichen Verbräuche o.ä. geht: er meint ohne andere Angabe üblicherweise den 24h-Tag.

Aus anderem Kontext kann natürlich "Tag" auch einen anderen, kürzeren Zeitraum beschreiben; da ist dann aber üblicherweise die Nachtzeit egal mit einem Gewicht von 0 (bspw. wenn man den täglichen Kaffeekonsum oder täglich publizierten Artikel im Büro betrachtet). Im Kontext von Tag- und Nachtverkehr mag dies ein Fachterminus sein, der genau festgelegt ist. Ist die konkrete Uhrzeit nicht exakt definiert, nehme ich dann, das sie eher eine für die jeweilige Tageszeit typische Verkehssituation beschreiben, die ggf. auch die Übergangszeiten der Rushhour ausnehmen. In jedem Fall sind es im Kontext fest stehende Begriffe, dessen genaue zeitliche Bedeutung sich deshalb aus dem Kontext ergibt. Da höre ich durchaus einen Unterschied, wenn ich vom *täglichen* Verkehr rede (über 24h), oder vom Tagesverkehr (zur üblichen oder definierten Zeit tagsüber) oder vom Nachtverkehr (zur üblichen oder definierten Zeit nachts).

Ergibt sich die Bedeutung nicht aus dem Kontext und will man andere, kürzere Zeiträume als 24h referenzieren, so sollte man den Zeitraum immer explizit angeben. Meint man den Zeitraum mit Tages*licht*, so kann man genau eben jenes Wort nutzen. Möglich wären auch bspw. für den genannten Zeitraum von 6h-22h 'tagsüber' oder auch nur 'tags' zu nutzen - aber das das ist dann nicht klar definiert und braucht explizite Nennung des Zeitraums.

Comment: Zitat: *»Will man ausdrücklich andere, kürzere Zeiträume als 24h referenzieren, so sollte man den Zeitraum immer explizit angeben.«* So? Warum? Wenn ich sage *»Ich habe den ganzen Tag gearbeitet, ich will jetzt meine Ruhe.«* Warum sollte ich da *»den ganzen Tag«* durch irgend etwas expliziteres ersetzen? Inwiefern würde das die Verständlichkeit meines Satz erhöhen? Wenn ich sage *»Ich habe von 8:30 bis 18:00 Uhr gearbeitet ...«* verbessert das nicht die Begründung für meinen Wunsch nach Ruhe. Außerdem ist in diesem Beispiel die genaue Dauer des  "Tages" auch völlig unerheblich.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast siehe meinen zweiten Absatz. Was Du beschreibst ist m.E. die Nutzung von "Tag" im eindeutigen Kontext, der dann einen ggf. auch gar nicht genau spezifizierten kürzeren Zeitraum beschreibt als 24h.

Comment: Den ersten Absatz kann ich so nicht mitgehen. Grade im Bereich Wetter wird es eindeutig: "Im Verlauf des Tages kommt es zu Regen." wird wohl jeder als "tagsüber"/"wenn es hell ist" interpretieren. Kein Meteorologe würde das spezifizieren auf "Zwischen 06:00 und 22:00 Uhr kommt es zu Regen".

Comment: Zum zweiten Absatz: Im meinem Fall ist genau das das Problem. Mir ist es egal ob ein Auto tags/nachts fährt, mein Zeitrahmen sind 24h, hier greift dein Beispiel sehr gut, ich rede daher oft vom täglichen Verkehr. Für den Lärmtechniker nebenan ist genau die Unterscheidung in täglichen Verkehr und nächtlichen Verkehr relevant.

Comment: Following these comments and the edit in the original question I elaborated a bit more what I mean with 'understand from context'.

Answer (score 0):

Ja

- Kalendertag
- Arbeitstag
- Manntag (8h)
- 24 Stunden

Der Chef fragt: "Wie lange brauchen Sie dafür?"

Wenn jetzt Mo. 13:00 Uhr ist, und Du brauchst einen ganzen Arbeitstag dafür, dann sag das so. Oder "Bis morgen 13 Uhr etwa, wenn ich den Auftrag von Winkelhammer so lange liegen lasse."

Manntag ist außerhalb des Geschäftslebens ungebräuchlich und wird zum Kalkulieren von Arbeitsleistungen verwendet, unabhängig vom Geschlecht der Person, die die Arbeit verrichtet, übrigens, oft als Teil einer Mannschaft.

Füŕ den Teil der 24h, an dem es hell ist kann man, wenn Missverständnisse drohen

- zwischen Sonnenauf- und -untergang
- tagsüber
- zw. 6 und 18 Uhr

und so weiter sagen, je nach dem, was man ausdrücken möchte und wie genau man es sagen kann. Meist ist aus dem Kontext klar, wovon die Rede ist, etwa dass Rechnungen in Kalendertagen fällig werden, oder dass sich eine Blüte abhängig vom Sonnenlicht öffnet.

Comment: Zur Ergänzung, nicht als Kritik an der Antwort: Ich arbeite im Bereich Software und habe das Wort "Manntag" schon sehr lange nicht mehr gehört. Das Wort "Personentag" (PT) hat sich stattdessen bei uns seit Jahren durchgesetzt.

Comment: Im Kontext dieser Frage finde ich es wichtig, anzumerken, dass Manntage/Personentage eben *keine* feste Zeiteinheit sind. "2 Personentage" können beispielsweise eine Gesamtdauer von 16h beschreiben, aber auch eine Gesamtdauer von nur 8h, wenn dafür 2 Personen die Arbeit verrichten. (Genau das ist der Grund, wieso man von "Personentagen" statt einfach von "Tagen" spricht.)

Comment: Ich stimme Mapper da zu und möchte ergänzen: Arbeitstag spezifiziert eine konkrete Art von Tagen (Mo-Sa), nicht den Zeitraum. Vielleicht mag das vor Urzeiten mal gegolten haben, dass ein Arbeitstag 8h hat, das würde ich in der modernen Welt von Gleitzeit, Schichtarbeit und flexiblen Arbeitszeitmodellen aber als abgeschafft betiteln.

Comment: @e-shirt: Mo-Fr sind Werktage, was ein Arbeitstag ist hängt davon ab, was man für einen Arbeitsvertrag hat oder wie man sich als Selbständiger die Arbeit einteilt. Richtig ist, dass 8h heute nicht mehr die Norm ist, außer in Branchen, in denen im 3-Schichtsystem gearbeitet wird, weil der Tag nun mal 24h hat. "Es dauert einen Arbeitstag" hängt also vom jeweiligen Arbeitsplatz ab und ist nebenbei wohl als mit Schätzfehlern behaftet zu verstehen. Jedenfalls dauert es nicht einen Werktag, weil ein Werktag eine Typisierung ist, kein Zeitraum.

Comment: auch deine eigene Begründung nehme ich gerne dafür an, warum weder Arbeits- noch Werktage eine treffende Umschreibung für mein Problem sind. Werktage sind übrigens gem. §3 BUrlG alle Tage, die nicht Sonn- und Feiertage sind, also regelmäßig Mo-Sa, wo du mich da schon so dezent korrigierst ;-)

Comment: @e-shirt "Manntag" würde heutzutage wohl als Diskriminierung nicht-männlicher Personen betrachtet, man sollte daher das neutrale "Personentag" verwenden. Ich kenne den "Arbeitstag" (nicht mit "Werktag" zu verwechseln, vgl. user unknowns Kommentar) als Einheit (mit Abkürzung AT) für Aufwandsplanung und -erfassung in Projekten. Der AT könnte also prinzipiell in Arbeitsstunden umgerechnet werden, wobei der Umrechnungsfaktor unternehmensspezifisch sein kann. In der Rolle als Maßeinheit hat der AT nichts damit zu tun, wieviele Personen an welchen Tagen und zu welchen Uhrzeiten gearbeitet haben.

Comment: "Würde wohl als Diskriminierung betrachtet" ist auch so ein Unsinn. Man unterstellt einer anonymen, spekulativen Masse eine fehlerhafte, unsinnige Interpretation, um darauf Rücksicht zu nehmen - konkret also auf niemanden und niemand ist verantwortlich. Was soll es denn Männern nützen, wenn man das Arbeitspensum in Manntagen ausdrückt? An den Haaren herbeigezogen, wie so vieles. Aber man hat der Welt wieder gezeigt, was für ein furchtloser Freiheitskämpfer man ist in diesem tyrannischen, patriarchalen System!

Answer (score -1):

Tja, das ist eben so. Der Zweck einer Sprache ist, Träger für Ideen zu sein, die vom Kopf eines Menschen in den Kopf eines oder mehrerer anderer Menschen gelangen sollen. Dazu wird die Idee auf der Seite des Senders mit Hilfe der Sprache codiert, dann in Form von Schallwellen oder geschriebener Schrift zum Empfänger übertragen, und der verwendet dann wieder eine Sprache, diesmal zu decodieren, und so landet die Idee dann im Kopf des Empfängers.

Dabei müssen Sprachen nicht besonders präzise sein. Präzision steht auf der imaginären Anforderungsliste für lebende Sprachen ziemlich weit unten.  Es kann durchaus vorkommen, dass der Empfänger bei dem oben beschriebenen Vorgang andere Ideen decodiert als der Sender codiert hat. Meist sind das ähnliche Ideen, aber eben nicht ganz gleich. Oft sind auch mehrere Interpretationen möglich, zwischen denen der Sender dann mehr oder weniger unbewusst auswählt. Dabei hilft ihm der Kontext, innerhalb dessen er die Nachricht erhalten hat.

> Ich habe den ganzen Tag gearbeitet, ich will jetzt meine Ruhe haben.

Bei diesem Satz ist kein 24-Stunden-Intervall gemeint, nicht mal der von Sonnenlicht erhellte Tag, sondern ein Zeitraum von nur 8 oder 9 Stunden, in denen man werktätig war.

> In 5 Tagen ist Weihnachten.

Hier sind keine 8-stündigen Arbeitsphasen gemeint, sondern Kalendertage, also 24-Stunden-Intervalle.

Der Unterschied erschließt sich aus dem Kontext und liegt klar genug vor, um ohne Missverständnis verstanden zu werden. Mehr Genauigkeit ist nicht erforderlich.

---

Wenn die Idee, die der Empfänger verstanden hat, erheblich von der Idee abweicht, die der Sender gemeint hat, spricht man von einem Missverständnis. Das ist dann ein Fehler in der Übertragung. Wenn sich viele solche gleichartigen Fehler beim Gebrauch desselben Begriffes häufen, wird man Maßnahmen ergreifen, um dieses konkrete Missverständnis zu beseitigen. Im vorliegenden Fall müsste man für eine der beiden Bedeutungen von *Tag* einen anderen Begriff finden. Wenn das passiert, verändert sich die Sprache. Sie entwickelt sich. Das macht sie aber nur wenn der Druck, der auf die Sprache wirkt, groß genug ist. Im Fall von *Tag* ist der Druck eindeutig zu gering um eine Veränderung zu bewirken.

Eine Sprache ist wie eine Tier- oder Pflanzenart. Sie entwickelt sich nach den Gesetzten der Evolution. Das heißt, jede Sprache erfüllt ihren Zweck gerade so gut wie es gerade mal notwendig ist. So wie auch jede Spezies gerade mal so an seine Umwelt angepasst ist, dass es aus der aktuellen Generation die nächste Generation hervorbringt. Besser als dieses Minimum zu sein ist für das Überleben der Art nicht notwendig. Und so, wie keine Tier- oder Pflanzenart perfekt ist, ist auch keine Sprache perfekt. So funktioniert nun mal die Evolution.

Comment: Ich werde nie verstehen, warum vernünftige Antworten Downvotes erhalten.

Comment: Mich würde vor allem interessieren, was die Gründ für die Downvotes sind. Ich bin nämlich überzeugt davon, dass meine Antwort weder falsch noch spekulativ oder sonstwas ist, sondern genau erklärt, warum so viele Begriffe mehrdeutig sind, und warum das auch so in Ordnung ist.

Comment: meinerseits liegt das an mehreren Punkten. "Tja das ist eben so" ist für mich keine besonders zufriedenstellende Art, eine sachliche Antwort zu beginnen. Hinzu kommt, dass ich nach einer Lösung eines konkreten sprachlichen Problems in meinem spezifischen Alltag suche und eine Abhandlung über das Sender-Empfänger-Modell bekomme. Außerdem ist die Aussage sage, dass Sprache nicht präzise sein muss mMn völliger Humbug, genau darum geht es ja in meinem Problem, dass die Sprache für meinen Anwendungsfall nicht präzise genug ist. und ich daher nach einer präziseren Lösung suche.

Comment: "Im vorliegenden Fall müsste man für eine der beiden Bedeutungen von Tag einen anderen Begriff finden." Genau, dass ist ja das von mir geschilderte Problem, was hier von dir einfach nur aufgegriffen und eben nicht beantwortet wird.
"Wenn das passiert, verändert sich die Sprache. Sie entwickelt sich. Das macht sie aber nur wenn der Druck, der auf die Sprache wirkt, groß genug ist." Ich will nicht die allgemeine Sprache verändern, sondern mich präsize mit meinen Kollegen absprechen können.